# HEXAGON Halide Tools 2.3: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi

Tags: clang++, halide, hexagon-dsp

I did not get response from Qualcomm forum so I decided to post here. When I was trying to run examples of Halide for Hexagon by running `make run` as written in the document. Then I got the following issue. The -lc++abi is missing.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -I /opt/qcom/Hexagon_SDK/4.3.0.0/tools/HALIDE_Tools/2.3.03/Halide/include -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -g -fno-rtti -rdynamic conv3x3_generator.cpp /opt/qcom/Hexagon_SDK/4.3.0.0/tools/HALIDE_Tools/2.3.03/Halide/lib/libHalide.a /opt/qcom/Hexagon_SDK/4.3.0.0/tools/HALIDE_Tools/2.3.03/Halide/tools/GenGen.cpp -o /opt/qcom/Hexagon_SDK/4.3.0.0/tools/HALIDE_Tools/2.3.03/Halide/Examples/build/offload/hexagon_benchmarks/bin/conv3x3.generator  -lz -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked the /usr/lib and find. So it should be there?

```
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1.0
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1
./llvm-10/lib/libc++abi.so.1.0
./llvm-10/lib/libc++abi.so.1
```

Did I miss anything or make anything stupid? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running with `-v` as the error message suggested? What's the value of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Comment: Assuming you're on Ubuntu... do you have `libc++-dev` and `libc++-10-dev` installed?

Answer (score 0):

`ld` is your system's host linker -- that's GNU BFD `ld`.  `clang++` must be in your `PATH` but it's the host `clang++` and not the `hexagon-clang++` that would be with Halide/Hexagon tools.

Comment: Yes, they are NOT hexagon-clang++. Here is the info: `/usr/bin/clang++`

clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

linker is: `/usr/bin/ld`

Comment: You should not expect the host `clang++` to work for hexagon.  For a relevant example about one reason why --  the `libc++abi`/`libc++` libraries are built for the host architecture and not hexagon.  You must use `hexagon-clang++` from the Hexagon Tools.

Comment: Yes. I also tried hexagon-clang++ but then the pthread.h was missing. https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/hexagon-dsp-sdk/debugging/68719 I have been confused about this question for several days. Still can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: It's pretty unfortunate that the toolchain does not ship with conventional behavior for finding the OS includes/libraries.  The SDK comes with examples but reproducing the results may be challenging.  I think you want to make a hexagon shared object with C++ sources, to be loaded by a fastrpc shell program.  I'll see if I can make a simpler example than the ones in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks!. The aim for me is to have some demo run on snapdragon device since I am developing some pipeline using hexagon DSP.

Comment: The problem has been solved. See my new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the person from Qualcomm. I am not supposed to use either `/usr/bin/clang++` nor `hexagon-clang++`. I downloaded `clang+llvm-7.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz` from `https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/`. You should use clang++ under the bin folder after you extract it. Now it works for me.